# calendar to check the date and then search 3 months back and add up the days of those months

Tags: date, calculator, cal

I want to use the cal command or the date command to display the current day,
then I want it to display 3 months before the current date, 
then add up all the days in those 3 months up to the current day.
Is there a way to do this?

So today's date is displayed as:

```
Fri Dec 19 13:23:36 GMT 2014
```

3 months ago would be:

```
Fri Sep 19 13:23:36 GMT 2014
```

I want all the days added up by Linux from September 19th to December 19th, then display the result of that calculation.

Comment: What should the result be on the 31st of May?

Comment: 28 th February as it is the last day of the month and the 31st of May is the last day of the month this was a good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` and GNU `date`

```
#grab today's date in YYYYMMDD format
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
#grab date as of 3 months ago in YYYYMMDD format
three_months_ago=$(date +%Y%m%d --date='3 months ago')

#now convert dates to "seconds since epoch" format, and then divide the difference  by 60*60*24 to convert from seconds to days
printf '%d\n' $(( ($(date --date=$today +%s) - \
  $(date --date=$three_months_ago +%s))/(60*60*24) ))
91
```

Comment: thank you can you just give me a quick explanation please it looks a bit confusing

Comment: @user2995836, see if the comments help

Comment: For GNU `date`, _3 months ago_ on 2014-05-31 is 2014-03-03. You'll also be off by one day when across one of the DST shifts in timezones where they apply. For instance, there are 89 days between 2014-02-21 and 2014-05-21, but your solution would report 88 in most timezones that change their clock for daylight saving.

Comment: Note that that syntax is `zsh`, not `bash`. In `bash`, you need to quote variables and arithmetic expansions.